# TypeError: numpy.float64 object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error

Error I got when running the Python script:
[image: How to solved TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable]

#### Code Used

```py
arr = np.array([[3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4]])


total = sum(sum(arr))

mean = sum(sum(arr))/(3*3)

for i in arr :
    vr= i - mean
    for med in vr**2 :             
        print(sum(med))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ade :)  Please use proper formatting for code. Just posting a link is considered bad-practice (images can be embedded, to show directly). Read [ask] and take the [tour] get an introduction.

Comment: You're question is further missing the desired outcome. What do you want to achieve with the code, print out a single number "21" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`med` is a number (float) and hence you cannot take the sum of it (its sum is itself). Also, the main point of using Numpy is to avoid loop and do array calculations at once. Something like this:

```
arr = np.array([[3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4]])

total = arr.sum()
mean = total/arr.size #equivalent of total=arr.mean()
vr = ((arr - mean)**2).sum() #equivalent of var=np.var(arr)*arr.size
```

Comment: Is the current right-hand side of `mean` assignment really equivalent to `total=arr.mean()` ? Anyway I tested with a [difference between both calculation methods](https://ideone.com/8ySNzd)

Comment: @hc_dev It should be. It calculates the mean of the array: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html. In your link, you are using python2 in which `/` would result in integer in both dividend and divisor are integer (which is the case in this example). Replace it with `mean = float(arr.sum())/arr.size` and you will see they result in the same output. Python3 however, you will not need this change as it results in float by default.

Answer (score 0):

#### Cause of the error

You got this error:

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

You are using a for-loop to iterate over an assumed array:

```py
    for med in vr**2 :
```

The expression `vr**2` is not an *array*, but a primitive *float*.

Thus you get this error.

#### Solution

Remove the second for-loop:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4]])

total = sum(sum(arr))
mean = sum(sum(arr))/(3*3)

for i in arr :
    vr = i - mean
    print(sum(vr**2))
```

Output is 3 lines for each sum:

```
2
14
5
```

Try this code as [demo in IDEone](https://ideone.com/aH6Ky5)

---

Advice:
Always post error-outputs as plain text in the question body (not only in title, not as image). So we can copy paste.